# Invalid address on realloc

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I am building a program, that reads a giant stdin full of Words. I want to divide the input into strings of 100 Characters max. So here is my code.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static char* string = "\0";

void getChar(char new){
    if (strcmp(string,"\0") == 0){
        free(string);
        string = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
        if (string == NULL){
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        string[0] = new;
    } else {
        char* newString = (char*) realloc(string, sizeof(string)+sizeof(char));
        if (newString == NULL){
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        string = newString;
        string[strlen(string)]=new;
    }
    if (strlen(string) > 100){
        printf("%s\n",string);
        dosomething(string);
        string = "\0";
    }
}

void getInput(){
    int temp;
    while((temp = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF){
        getChar((char) temp);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    getInput();
}
```

After compiling and executing the Code i emmediately get an error saying:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./sort: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x08f02008 //ofc this address always changes
```

In a later version, i will filter by \n with Strings being greater than 100 Characters being ingnored.

Comment: Suggestion: avoid C++ keywords like `new` in C programs.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(string)` actually tells you the size of `string` *itself* (the pointer, since that's what `string` is), not the length of the thing it points to. You need to keep track of the length of the string yourself, either by using `strlen` (which means it must always have a terminating zero byte) or with a separate length variable.

There's lots of other bugs. Your first `free(string)` occurs before `string` points to space you allocated, which is fatal.

Comment: @TorhanBartel: Only if you always put a terminating zero byte, which you don't. For example, you do `string[0] = new;` -- but that just stores one character, it doesn't store a string. So you *can't* use `strlen` on it either.

Comment: OK so i need an memory addres for string... like malloc it in main()?

Comment: and i need to set \0 characters

Comment: If you store it as a string, you can use `strlen` to find its length (less the terminating zero byte).

Comment: If you can remember that sizeof is actually resolved at compile time, then it's a lot easier to remember to use strlen, since you won't know the length of the string at compile time.